# RecyclerView adapter don't want to reuse ViewHolders

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I faced a problem of memory leak.
I have a fragment with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and with one fragment inside(there are more, I left one just for the test).
This fragment has RecyclerView with a few different ViewHolders.

For example, this is a simple `ViewHolder` and it is used only in one place in `RecyclerView` - as a header.

```
public class CurrencyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.currency_date)
    TextView currencyDate;
    @BindView(R.id.currency_usd)
    TextView currencyUsd;
    @BindView(R.id.currency_eur)
    TextView currencyEur;
    @BindView(R.id.currency_info)
    LinearLayout currencyInfo;

    public CurrencyViewHolder(View itemView, boolean nightMode) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bind(CbrResponse response) {
        currencyDate.setText(String.format("asdsdf %s", response.getDate()));
        currencyUsd.setText(String.format("USD %,.2f", response.getUSD().getValue()));
        currencyEur.setText(String.format("EUR %,.2f", response.getEUR().getValue()));
    }
}
```

But, as you can see, on this pic [image]

I've got 12 instances of this class. I've made 12 transactions to another fragment from this one and my **`ViewHolders` were recreated for some reason!**

And this thing I think causes the memory leak I have. I'm not sure which code do you want So I put some adapter methods in case you want to see it.

`NewsListRecyclerAdapter` is my adapter where are the code below is executed. Pay attention that Only once intance of this class is created!.

[image: Here is a memory graph. You clearly can see momory increase. manual GC does not help. And after a few more transactions I'll get OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION]

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == Constant.TYPE_TEASER) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_teaser_recycler, parent, false);
                return new TeaserViewHolder(view, reference, isNightMode);
            } else if (viewType == Constant.TYPE_CURRENCY_HEADER) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_currency, parent, false);
                return new CurrencyViewHolder(view, isNightMode);
            } else if (viewType == Constant.TYPE_TEASER_VISITED) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_teaser_recycler, parent, false);
                return new TeaserVisitedViewHolder(view, reference, isNightMode);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "there is no type that matches the type " + viewType
                            + " + make sure your using types correctly");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            NewsListItem item = sortedList.get(position);
            if (holder instanceof TeaserVisitedViewHolder) {
                ((TeaserVisitedViewHolder) holder).bind(item);
            } else if (holder instanceof TeaserViewHolder) {
                ((TeaserViewHolder) holder).bind(item);
            } else if (holder instanceof CurrencyViewHolder) {
                ((CurrencyViewHolder) holder).bind(item.getCurrency());
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "there is no type that matches the type " + holder.getClass().getSimpleName()
                                + " + make sure your using types correctly");
            }
        }
```

**UPD**

Here is my framgnet with ViewPager:

```
public class PagerListsFragment extends NightModeFragment {
    private final String LOG_TAG = PagerListsFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    @BindView(R.id.circlePagerListsIndicator)
    TextCirclePageIndicator pageIndicator;
    @BindView(R.id.settings_button)
    ImageButton settingsButton;
    @BindView(R.id.pager_lists_header)
    FrameLayout pagerListsHeader;
    @BindView(R.id.pagerLists)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.linear_layout)
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

//    ArticlesFragment articlesFragment;
//    FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment;


    PagerListsFragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("PagerListsFragment", "onCreate");
        fragmentAdapter = new PagerListsFragmentAdapter(getContext(), getChildFragmentManager());
//        articlesFragment = new ArticlesFragment();
//        favouritesFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("PagerListsFragment", "onViewCreated");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerLists);
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

        viewPager.setPageMargin((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.lists_pager_margin));

        pageIndicator =
                (TextCirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.circlePagerListsIndicator);
        pageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

        pagerListsHeader = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_lists_header);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        final int topMarginUp = 0;
        final int topMarginDown = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
        setTopMargin(linearLayout, topMarginDown);

        ImageButton settingsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(v -> ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openSettings());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("PagerListsFragment", "onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("PagerListsFragment", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.fragment_list_paged;
    }


    private void setTopMargin(View view, int topMarginInPx) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
                (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topMargin = topMarginInPx;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    public static PagerListsFragment getInstace(Bundle extra) {
        PagerListsFragment fragment = new PagerListsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(extra);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

and here is my fragment where RecyclerView is:

```
public class NewsFragment extends BaseNewsFragment implements NewsViewState,
        TeaserViewHolder.OnItemClickListener {

    private final Category category = new Category(Category.NEWS);

    @InjectPresenter
    NewsPresenter presenter;

    protected NewsListRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    protected EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener scrollListener;

    @BindView(R.id.news_recycler)
    protected RecyclerView newsRecycler;
    @BindView(R.id.refresh)
    protected SwipeRefreshLayout refresh;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("NewsFragment", "onCreate");
        adapter = new NewsListRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), this);
        presenter.loadNewsAndCurrency(0, true, category);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(manager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                presenter.loadNewsAndCurrency(adapter.getItemCount(), false, category);
            }
        };
        newsRecycler.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        newsRecycler.setItemAnimator(null);
        newsRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
        newsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        refresh.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            scrollListener.reset(0, true);
            presenter.loadNewsAndCurrency(0, true, category);
            if (!DEBUG) {
                FlurryAgent.logEvent(FlurryHelper.USER_NEWS_LIST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("NewsFragment", "onDestroy");
        if (newsRecycler != null) {
            newsRecycler.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTeasersLoaded(List<NewsListItem> teasers, boolean refresh) {
        adapter.addAll(teasers, refresh);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTeaser(NewsListItem item) {
        Log.d("BaseNewsFragment", "Removing item.getType():" + item.getType());
        if (item.getTeaser().getCategoryId() == category.getCategoryInt()) {
            adapter.remove(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addTeaser(NewsListItem item) {
        if (item.getTeaser().getCategoryId() == category.getCategoryInt()) {
            adapter.add(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCurrencyLoaded(NewsListItem currencyItem) {
        adapter.add(currencyItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(NewsListItem teaser) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onNewsSelected(teaser.getTeaser().getUuid(), category.getCategoryInt());
        adapter.add(teaser);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNightMode() {
        adapter.setNightMode(isNightMode);
        newsRecycler.setBackgroundColor(getCurrentBackgroundColor());
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress() {
        refresh.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgress() {
        refresh.setRefreshing(true);
    }
}
```

I can't swipe fragments because I have only one framgent left in ViewPager (just for the sake of test.)

Comment: what you really mean by "I've made 12 transactions to another fragment from this one"?

Comment: Have you used ViewPager ?

Comment: @Ewoks I mean that I navigate between this recyclerView fragment and other fragment 12 times.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Yes, I use ViewPager to store fragment with RecyclerView. FragmentStatePagerAdapter is his adapter

Comment: I am not sure I see the issue here.. Your RecyclerView has 12 visible items, no? Therefore there are 12 ViewHolders in use. If RecyclerView has 1200 items all in all, but just 12 are visible just 12 ViewHolders will be created and content of those will be filled with 12 of 1200 items that are currently visible. So what is the problem you have?

Comment: @Ewoks I have only 3 view visible at once, Also (this is very important) when I only scroll my RecyclerView(but not navigate between fragments) I have only 5 viewholders created in total. Here you see 34 and I haven't even scrolled!

Comment: Is your `ViewPager` inside `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: @azizbekian it is inside FrameLayout.

Comment: tried, for testing to `setRecyclerListener()` ?

Comment: @pskink It invoke callback when I scroll only. When I make navigation it the callback onViewRecycled never called!

Comment: what navigation do you mean?

Comment: @pskink between fragments. I navigate between settings and PagerListsFragment  12 times and 12 instances of viewholder is created. I've mentioned it it the post above

Comment: So did you Forced GC before Dumping Heap?

Comment: @KeivanEsbati yes, I did that. And one important note - No references to those ViewHolders, but they DO exist. Mystic.

Answer (score 0):

How Many Time your fragment got **recreated**? The 12 `ViewHolder` count may be from new `Fragment` being recreated when you swipe with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` resulting in recreation of `RecyclerView`, `RecyclerAdapter` and `ViewHolders`.

Also have you tried to use `Initiate GC` before looking at heap? They may be `GC` waiting to collect **old destroyed** view but since there is enough memory available `GC` won't collent those yet..

Comment: as you see on I picture I attached I have only one instance of ReyclerAdapter. It is created in fragment's onCreate method whtich is called also once only. I'll add more comments to the picture

Comment: Can you please post your fragment code too ^^ It helps a lot